# 願わくばこのまま穏やかなままとはいかねぇもんだろうか meaning?

Tags: meaning, grammar

In episode 3 of **Shingeki no Kyojin** at 8:30 there is this sentence:

> 願わくば**このまま穏やかなままとはいかねぇもんだろうか**

I tried my hardest but I couldn't understand what it means; can any expert here explain the structures used in 「このまま穏やかなままとはいかねぇもんだろうか」?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

- **願わくば**: "Hopefully, ..." see: [What conjugation of 願う is 願わくば, and what does it mean here?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30245/5010)
- **このまま**: "like this"; "as it is now"; "at this rate"
- **穏やかなまま**: "the calm/peaceful status continues"
- **とはいかねぇ**: = とはいかない, "won't pass as ～", "cannot expect ～", See: [Where does the いかない in ～わけにはいかない come from?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2882/5010) and [What does 「そうもいかなくて」 mean in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/37093/5010)

  - **と**: the quotative particle that marks the "content" of the verb 行く. see: [Function of と when used with 続く](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/68125/5010)
  - **は**: the topic particle
  - **いかねぇ**: = いかない, "will not pass/go"
- **もん**: adds the meaning of "the way it should be", see: [The meanings of ものだ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43083/5010) and [Alternative meaning of ものか](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/66245/5010)
- **だろうか**: "I wonder if ～", see: [だろう in question context?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/62238/5010)

> 願わくば「このまま穏やかなまま」とはいかねぇもんだろうか?
>
> (literally) Hopefully, I wonder if it should not go like things stay calm as it is now?
>
> I wonder if I can expect everything will stay as calm as now?

Comment: thank you very much for your breakdown!! it is much clearer now! Guess I need to get accustomed to the negative verb usage tendency of Jap language to express affirmative meaning.

Comment: @ĐỗHùng try to avoid this abbreviation since it has offensive connotations. If you must abbreviate, use “jp” or “Jpn”, but best is just to use the whole word.